# Explain like I'm five: "see" index entries

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, learning, makeindex

Can someone please explain like I'm five: What is the correct syntax for making index entries like this?

```
hierarchy: see `polymorphism`

overloading,
    operator: see `operator overloading`
```

I'm using packages `hyperref` and `imakeidx`.

What *exactly* is the "see" syntax, and how am I supposed to invoke it? I'm confused about the difference between

```
\index{x|see{y}}
\index{x|see {y}}
\index{x|\see{y}}
\index{x|\see {y}}
\indexentry{x|see{y}}
```

I'm particularly confused because some answers (like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259260/126270)) mention "the `\see` macro", which matches my intuition that special words in TeX should be spelled with backslashes... but then I see people writing actual index entries *without* the backslash, and somehow it still works!

Corollary: What is the format of `{y}` in the above examples? Can I (and should I) be using things like `{e@$e$}` or `{constant!Euler's}` in a "see"?

Corollary: Does `makeindex` recognize any more special verbs besides "see"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First the easy part: `\indexentry` should never be used in a document; it's not generally defined and is only used for writing to the `.idx` file that `makeindex` will convert to an `.ind` file that LaTeX can input.

The syntax is

```
\index{abc|see{x}}
```

A space is irrelevant, so `\index{abc|see {x}}` is acceptable as well. You must not use a backslash, it's a job for `makeindex` to add it at the proper place.

The definition of `\see` is

```
\newcommand*\see[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}
```

but it could be changed in the document preamble to suit your needs.

The following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

a\index{x|see{y}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

will produce an `.idx` file containing

\indexentry{x|see{y}}{1}

that will be processed by `makeindex` producing an `.ind` file with

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item x, \see{y}{1}

\end{theindex}
```

You see that the second argument to `\see` is the page number, which one usually wants to omit, but by changing the definition of `\see` other effects can be obtained.

The `makeidx` package (and so `imakeidx` as well) defines also `\seealso`, so you can use

```
\index{z|seealso{u}}
```

and the same about `\see` can be said. You can use any two argument command in the same fashion.

The part before `|` can be any legal entry for `\index`, so

```
\index{a@bcd|see{x}}
\index{a!b|see{x}}
```

are both good, with the expected result according to the rules of `makeindex`. The only difference will be that “*see* x“ appears instead of the page number.